# How can I compare Regular Expression Objects by their functionality

Tags: python

The two following regular expression objects that match a decimal number are functionally equal:

```
a = re.compile(r"""\d +  # the integral part
                   \.    # the decimal point
                   \d *  # some fractional digits""", re.X)
b = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d*")
```

How can I compare them by their functionality?
In this case `a == b` should be `True`.

Comment: Long story short: you build the corresponding dfa, minimize it and compare.

Comment: Don't think this is really a duplicate. I presume OP wants to compare them *from* Python. Not using some external regex to DFA tool.